# simplexml_load_string path to value

Tags: php, xml, soap

I get different XML strings via SOAP.

But it is very difficult for me to get the value from XML with PHP.

XML examples:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetUserInfoResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
        <GetUserInfoResult>
            <GetUserInfo>
                <User ID="23" />
            </GetUserInfo>
        </GetUserInfoResult>
    </GetUserInfoResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetListItemsResult>
                <listitems xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
     xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
                    <rs:data>
                        <z:row ows_ID="128" />
                    </rs:data>
                </listitems>
            </GetListItemsResult>
        </GetListItemsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to get the id.

I tried it like this:

```
$xml_element = simplexml_load_string($responseContent);
$name_spaces = $xml_element->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml_element->children($name_spaces['soap'])
    ->Body
    ->children($name_spaces['rs'])
    ->GetListItemsResponse
    ->GetListItemsResult
    ->listitems
    ->{'rs:data'}
    ->{'z:row'}['ows_ID'][0];
```

But most time I dont know how to get my value.

Is it possible to display a whole array or how do I get the path to the value?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to get the value of 'ows_ID' is to use the `SimpleXMLElement` [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method and also add the namespaces for the child elements.

You can use the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method to get the value for 'ows_ID';

For example:

```
$responseContent = <<<XML
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetListItemsResult>
                <listitems xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
     xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
     xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
                    <rs:data>
                        <z:row ows_ID="128" />
                    </rs:data>
                </listitems>
            </GetListItemsResult>
        </GetListItemsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;

$xml_element = simplexml_load_string($responseContent);
$name_spaces = $xml_element->getNamespaces(true);

$rows = $xml_element
    ->children($name_spaces['soap'])
    ->Body
    ->children()
    ->GetListItemsResponse
    ->GetListItemsResult
    ->listitems
    ->children($name_spaces['rs'])
    ->children($name_spaces['z']);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $ows_ID =  $row->attributes()->ows_ID;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7dNf9)